# Docker: run --net=host option changes to different shell in container

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, docker

Goal: Currently trying to connect to a MySQL database on the host from the container.

Action: I have seen several answers to this problem, one being to run the container in host only mode with the `--net=host` option, so I can access the host using `localhost/127.blah`.

Result: Normally, when I execute the command

```
docker run -it [image_id] bash
```

I get a shell prompt with `[user]@[container_id]` (i.e., `username@12345abcdef`). However, when I execute the command

```
docker run --net=host -it [image_id] bash
```

it drops me to the same prompt **as the host, but no longer in bold** (specifically the prompt `[user]@[container_id]` is no longer in bold). I can tell I am in the container because of the file structure.

Question: What is happening? Am I one the right track to connecting to the database on the host? Why is it the same prompt and what is the significance of the change in font type from bold (host) to not bold (container)?

If it matters, the docker container is being created/ran inside a Vagrant machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container id you normally see in your shell prompt is your container hostname. When you use `--net=host`, your container hostname is the same as your host's hostname. You have removed the normal network namespace that containers have. So the bash prompt with your container will look similar to the prompt on the host of you display the same fields on each. You can see the formatting of the prompt by checking the value of `$PS1`.

---

Edit: here's a comparison of different values of `$PS1` from different base images (my host happens to be Debian):

```
$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

$ docker run -it --rm debian:latest
root@4aca692dc29d:/# echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
root@4aca692dc29d:/# exit
exit

$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu
root@b1eb8e51d672:/# echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
root@b1eb8e51d672:/# exit
exit

$ docker run -it --rm busybox
/ # echo $PS1
\w \$
/ # exit

$ docker run -it --rm centos
[root@abbfa9aa6968 /]# echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
[root@abbfa9aa6968 /]# exit
exit
```

Comment: OK. Needed to be sure. Why the change in coloring?

Comment: Compare the value of `$PS1` on your host and inside your container. There are likely some differences. Either that, or for some reason the tty option (`-t`) didn't make it to the container.

Comment: No, I agreed it was the container from the file structure, but I wasn't sure about the prompt. Thanks!

Comment: The prompt is based on the value of `$PS1` which can be different inside the container than your host.